# Hapi + Swagger, how to render HTML?

Tags: html, model-view-controller, swagger, hapi.js

I follow this document to create a simple swagger-hapi project. APIs defined in swagger.yaml are working fine.
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node

I wonder if I can render HTML with the request object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin, [hapi-swagger](https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger), that can be used specifically with hapi. No yaml file configuration required.

If you want to do templating with hapi, look at the [vision](https://github.com/hapijs/vision) and [inert](https://github.com/hapijs/inert) plugins. Vision allows you to use a template engine to render your html server-side.

Handlebars example:

```
const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 8000 });

const handler = function (request, reply) {

    reply.view('basic/index', {
        title: 'examples/views/handlebars/basic.js | Hapi ' + request.server.version,
        message: 'Hello World!'
    });
};

server.register(require('vision'), (err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.views({
        engines: { html: require('handlebars') },
        path: __dirname + '/templates'
    });

    server.route({ method: 'GET', path: '/', handler: handler });
});
```

Comment: okay, does it mean I can install this plugin to my existing hapi project, and swagger documentation will be available for me?

Comment: @karthikeayan see (https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger#tagging-your-api-routes)[tagging your routes]. once you register your plugin, you just need to add an `api` tag to any routes you want documented.